# How do I update the textbox when it is change?

Tags: vb.net

I am doing update so what I do was to use a select statement to grab from database. Then display it to their perspective textbox. But it did not update to the newly provided date but use the original date. Can someone please help? Do I need to use textChanged or there is other method?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load   

    Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT * FROM Card WHERE CardID='" & Request.QueryString("id") & "'"
    Dim CardDt As DataTable = DBadapter.GetDataTable(sqlstr)

    Dim count = 0

    TextBox1.Text = CardDt.Rows.Item(count).Item("Date")

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sqlstr2 As String = "Update Card Set Date='" & TextBox1.Text & "' WHERE Card_Code=" & MM_recordId

    Dim UpdateDt As DataTable = DBadapter.GetDataTable(sqlstr2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you be using `testDataTable.Rows.Item(count).Item("Code")` in the first place?  You're already looping through `testDataTable.Rows` so why is that not just `row("Code")`? Or, more correctly, `CStr(row("Code"))` or `row("Code").ToString()`?

Comment: But if I do that the data I get would all be the same.

Comment: Because you looping rows with `For Each`, `row` object will change on every loop.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `row.Item("Code")` ... ?

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to build an sql statement. this is a [security hazard.](https://xkcd.com/327/) use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: It's been a long time since my asp.net days, but if memory serves, the Page_Load event happens **before** the button_click, and this is the reason why you get the date that was saved in your database before the update statement was executed.

Comment: ok, But is there any way i could update the written text rather than the provided from the database ?

Comment: well i wanted it to display all the provided data from database so that user can easily change the data.

Comment: For now I want to get the value of the change text and not the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use IsPostBack at the page load.

```
If Not IsPostBack Then

   Code to read data from database

End If
```